# IBM Asset Monitor - Test Custom Function DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, sdk

I am following the steps in this link, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP8H/iot/analytics/tutorials/as_adding_complex_function_tutorial.html, and have created a function successfully.

My files can be found here, https://github.com/tiongghee/AssetMonitor

I have created the test script, test_my_custom_function.py, to test my function and have encountered the under-mentioned error.

```
C:\Users\TIONGGHEETAN\Desktop\projects>python3 test_my_custom_function.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_my_custom_function.py", line 6, in <module>
    from iotfunctions.base import BaseTransformer
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\iotfunctions\base.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .db import Database
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\iotfunctions\db.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import metadata as md
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\iotfunctions\metadata.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .pipeline import (CalcPipeline, DropNull, JobController, JobLogNull, Trace, AggregateItems)
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\iotfunctions\pipeline.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .stages import DataWriterSqlAlchemy, ProduceAlerts
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\iotfunctions\stages.py", line 15, in <module>
    import ibm_db
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 10, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 9, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
  File "D:\WIOTProgram_Files\python372\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you do a pip freeze > requirements.txt.  ?

Answer (score 0):

My python version is 3.7.2.

These are my pip libraries.
C:\Users\TIONGGHEETAN\Desktop\projects>pip freeze

- attrs==19.1.0 backcall==0.1.0 beautifulsoup4==4.8.2 bleach==3.1.0
  bleak==0.5.1 branca==0.3.1 bs4==0.0.1 certifi==2019.3.9
  chardet==3.0.4 click==6.7 colorama==0.4.1 combo==0.0.8
  confluent-kafka==1.3.0 custom==0.0.1 customTG==0.0.1 cycler==0.10.0
  Cython==0.29.7 decorator==4.4.0 defusedxml==0.5.0 dill==0.3.0
  docutils==0.15.2 entrypoints==0.3 Flask==1.0.2 folium==0.10.1
  future==0.18.2 geocoder==1.38.1 get==2019.4.13 graphviz==0.10.1
  ibm-cos-sdk==2.1.3 ibm-cos-sdk-core==2.6.0
  ibm-cos-sdk-s3transfer==2.6.0 ibm-db==3.0.1 ibm-db-sa==0.3.3
  idna==2.6 image-slicer==0.2.0 imageio==2.6.1 iotfunctions==2.0.3
  ipykernel==5.1.0 ipython==7.4.0 ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  ipywidgets==7.4.2 itsdangerous==0.24 jedi==0.13.3 Jinja2==2.10
  jmespath==0.9.4 joblib==0.14.1 jsonschema==3.0.1 jupyter==1.0.0
  jupyter-client==5.2.4 jupyter-console==6.0.0 jupyter-core==4.4.0
  kafka-python==1.4.7 kiwisolver==1.0.1 llvmlite==0.31.0 lxml==4.3.4
  MarkupSafe==1.0 matplotlib==3.0.3 mistune==0.8.4 nbconvert==5.4.1
  nbformat==4.4.0 networkx==2.4 nose==1.3.7 notebook==5.7.7
  numba==0.48.0 numpy==1.17.3 opencv-python==4.1.0.25 pandas==0.24.2
  pandocfilters==1.4.2 parso==0.3.4 pickleshare==0.7.5 Pillow==5.4.1
  plotly==4.4.1 post==2019.4.13 prometheus-client==0.6.0
  prompt-toolkit==2.0.9 psycopg2-binary==2.8.4 public==2019.4.13
  PyBluez==0.23 pydotplus==2.0.2 Pygments==2.3.1 pyod==0.7.5
  pyparsing==2.3.1 pyrsistent==0.14.11 pytesseract==0.2.6
  python-dateutil==2.8.0 pythonnet==2.4.0 pytz==2018.9
  PyWavelets==1.1.1 pywinpty==0.5.5 pyzmq==18.0.1 qtconsole==4.4.3
  query-string==2019.4.13 ratelim==0.1.6 request==2019.4.13
  requests==2.18.4 retrying==1.3.3 scikit-image==0.16.2
  scikit-learn==0.20.3 scipy==1.2.1 seaborn==0.9.0 Send2Trash==1.5.0
  six==1.12.0 sklearn==0.0 soupsieve==1.9.5 SQLAlchemy==1.3.10
  suod==0.0.2 tabulate==0.8.5 terminado==0.8.2 testpath==0.4.2
  tornado==6.0.2 traitlets==4.3.2 urllib3==1.22 Wave==0.0.2
  wcwidth==0.1.7 webencodings==0.5.1 Werkzeug==0.14.1
  widgetsnbextension==3.4.2 wordcloud==1.6.0 xlrd==1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the following entries in your requirements.txt for db2

```
ibm-db==3.0.1
ibm-db-sa==0.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

To update:
I encountered the same problem after updating requirements.txt.

My code are finally working now after I followed the instructions from here.
https://github.com/IBM/watson-analytics-dashboard/blob/master/README.md